Install como syntax error en consola python
quise empezar a hacer un proyecto de practica y al momento de hacer un entorno virtual tuve el siguiente problema, me pidieron utilizar:
python -m venv venv
Y me sale un error en "venv" diciendo: SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Busco cual puede ser el problema y leo que primero tenia que instalar el virtualenv con:
pip install virtualenv
Y me sale otra vez el mismo error pero con la palabra "install".
No se que error estoy cometiendo, probablemente sea algo muy simple pero no pude encontrar una solución en ninguna parte y no tengo a quien preguntar, soy nuevo en el ámbito de la programación.


El comando a de ejecutarse en la shell de comandos del sistema (cmd o PowerShell en tu caso). Lo estas ejecutando en el interprete interactivo de Python (REPL) y eso no es sintaxis valida del lenguaje, de ahí el error..

primero y principal estás entrando a la consola de python y no deberias hacerlo para ejecutar ese comando, abre una nueva consola (normal de cmd) y sin escribir nada colocas justo lo mismo que estabas escribiendo python -m venv venv donde el ultimo venv es el nombre de tu entorno (puede ser cualquier nombre) luego de esto deberia de instalarse.

Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.

Gracias. Revisando bien me di cuenta de que lo que estaba viendo en un tutorial era la consola de linux y por alguna razón me confundí con la de python. De vuelta gracias y pido disculpas por la ignorancia.

Para la creación de entornos virtuales te recomiendo leer la documentación oficial.
Te marca error porque estas "editando" un programa en python en esa terminal.
El comando debes ejecutarlo en el directorio de archivos donde deseas crear el entorno.
Ej: "C:>Python35\python -m venv c:\path\to\myenv"
El comando que intentas utilizar es "python -m venv 'tu_entorno'".
Entonces si te fijas si estas escribiendo mal el comando.
No necesitas instalar ningún modulo, ya Python te permite realizarlo de forma nativa.

Muchas gracias, lo de la documentación me viene perfecto ya que no había estudiado nada de entornos virtuales.
